# Logging into Skydrive using IE9 sends me into a redirect loop

Tags: windows-live, internet-explorer-9

When I try to login to https://skydrive.live.com/ using Internet Explorer 9 I get into a redirect loop where I'm redirected to https://login.live.com/, then back to https://skydrive.live.com/, then to https://login.live.com/ and so on until the loop is detected and the Windows Live login fails.

However, if I start Internet Explorer 9 using the **-extoff** (no add-ons) command line option I'm again able to login to Skydrive. Turning off all add-ons using the **Manage add-ons** dialog box has no effect and the login process still loops.

I have tried to delete all cookies and temporary internet files and uninstalled the Windows Live Login Assistant but this hasn't solved my problem. Also, FireFox does not have any problems performing the login.

I have used Fiddler to look at the traffic and I have noticed that after the *login* site redirects to *skydrive* the cookies sent to the *skydrive* site are different:

- Using IE9 wihout add-ons cookies like **RPSTAuth**, **MSPAuth**, **MSPProf** and **MSNPPAuth** are set and login is succesful.
- Using IE9 normally cookies like **wls**, **wlv**, **wlp**, **BP**, **LN**, **MUID**, **drua** and **HIC** are set and login gets into a redirect loop.

I'm on a corporate network with a proxy server that requires authentication making it hard for me to attempt the login using a different user on the computer.

What is going on with the **-extoff** command line option as opposed to disabling all add-ons in the dialog box and what can I do to be able to login to Skydrive without having to use that option?

Comment: Just to verify, you exited IE completely after clearing your cache/cookies correct?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue myself (I'm using IE9 RTM, just tried it).

I would suggest going to a different Live login website, log in/off and then go back to the SkyDrive page and try to login.  We are a Live@EDU user for our student population and this trick often helps them when they see this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to login to http://msdn.microsoft.com/ using my Live ID but logging into Skydrive still loops.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem you were having. I'm not sure if it's for the same reason, so what fixed it for me may not fix it for you (especially since I'm not sure *why* it fixed it for me).

Go to Tools-->Internet options-->Security and select Trusted sites. Then click on Sites and see if an entry for live.com is there. If so, try deleting it and restarting your browser. That did it for me.

Oddly enough, I was even able to add it back as a trusted site later on without getting that login loop. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this issue but I still lack a clear understanding of the source of the problem.

I did all sorts of stuff like deleting my user profile and downgrading to IE8 without solving the problem. Then I discovered that I had made a mistake trying to disable all addons. In the **Manage add-ons** dialog box there is a drop-down where you can select one of four categories of add-ons:

- All add-ons
- Currently loaded add-ons
- Run without permission
- Downloaded controls

I had disabled **All add-ons** but the problem persisted as described in the question. The confusing part is that **Run without permission** and **Downloaded controls** contain COM objects that also can run in the browser and they are not disabled if you only disable **All add-ons**.

Disabling all entries in all four categories made the problem go away. I then systematically reenabled add-ons in an attempt to determine which COM object was the culprit. However, even after reenabling all add-ons in all categories I no longer had the problem. Much happier but none the wiser.